# Which one should I say?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, differences

can somebody help me?

Which one should I say:

“I took a blood/urine test yesterday”

“I had a blood/urine test yesterday”
?

Thank you!

Comment: The second is better, but the first is often used.

Comment: And what if I’m asking someone what kind of tests the doctor ran on him? Which one should I use, ”what kind of tests did you take” or ”what kind of tests did you have”?

Comment: Normally, "have", for a "test" where the individual just sat there and had needles poked in him.  "Take" is generally reserved for the case where you write down answers on a piece of paper or some such.

Comment: In other words, when it’s about medical tests, it’s preferable to use “have.” And when it’s take a school/standardized test, it’s better to use “take.” However, if we say I’m running some lab tests, is it better to say “I did some tests and handed the reports to my boss”?

Comment: Could I also say, instead of “what kind of tests did you have”, “what kind of tests did they do/run?”